# Create an XML template for app response

Tags: php, xml, slim

So here is my code...

```
$app->post(
  '/chk_db',
    function () use ($app){
      require_once 'lib/mysql.php';
      $dx = connect_db('MyPhotos');

      //XML RESPONSE
      $app->response->setStatus(0);
      $res = $app->response();
      $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml';
      $view = $app->view();
      $view->setTemplatesDirectory('./');
      $oArray = array("Status"=> $dx.status, "code" => $dx.code);
      return $app->render('chkdb.xml', $oArray);
  }
);
```

I wanna know how to create the chkdb.xml template that can handle my input.. 
Then will output the following..

```
<MyPhotos>
   <Status>success</Status>
   <code>0</code>
</MyPhotos>
```

Thanks in advance....

EDIT: Answered.. Thanks alexw

Comment: Have you looked into Twig?  Should be able to render XML just as easily as HTML.

Comment: @alexw am a newbie in this area.. I go check that twig out...

Comment: How do I catch the Array passed by the `$app->render('some.xml, $somearray)` on the xml template? how do i handle that array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), you can just use the array keys in double-curly-brace placeholders.  So if your `somearray` were:

```
$somearray = [
    "status" => "success",
    "code" => 0,
    "messages" => [
        "msg1" => "Hello",
        "msg2" => "Goodbye"
    ]
];
```

Then you just make your XML template (`template.xml`):

```
<MyPhotos>
   <Status>{{status}}</Status>
   <code>{{code}}</code>
   <messages>
   {% for message in messages %}
      <message>{{message}}</message>
   {% endfor %}
   </messages>
</MyPhotos>
```

And render it:

```
$app->render("template.xml", $somearray);
```

To use Twig with Slim, you will need to include the [Slim-Views package](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views).  Configuration instructions are in the README.

Comment: This is good.. but the problem is that I got errors using twig... >.<
(and yes I dunno how to use them either... 

Do you know how to catch the array passed by the render on the template?

Is there any code I can use so i can got that data.... T^T
I'm feeling so dumb now...

Comment: What do you mean by "catch"?  Do you mean, access the data in `$somearray` from within the template?

Comment: That's what you're doing when you're using the placeholders.  `{{status}}` means, get the value that's keyed by "status".  If you have a multidimensional array, you can use the `.` operator for scope, or you can even loop through contents using the [for](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) tag.

Comment: Gocha.. finally manage to get the idea... the errors was cause by the mismatched placement of twig, slim folders, and composer.json etc...
I have recreate my project using the composer..

Thank you very much.. Now I can use twig....

Comment: Nice, sounds like a great start to a new project!

Comment: Hey.. just 1 more question.. If i have `array(array(somearray1), array(somearray2), .... , array(somearrayn));`  How would I handle them in the template? TIA

Comment: You should open this as a new question.

Comment: ow oki I made a new question... thanks...
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632804/how-to-handle-multidimensional-array-on-xml-template)